# Oracle - how to convert datetime to TZ format?

Tags: oracle

I have this time format:

```
2020-09-08 14:00:00
```

and I want to convert it to following which is from Sydney time to UTC:

```
2020-09-08T01:00:00Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, giving the answer considering that your data is actual `varchar2`:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(CAST(TO_DATE('2020-09-08 14:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  2     AS TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney',
  3    'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"')
  4    FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(CAST(TO_DATE
--------------------
2020-09-08T18:30:00Z

SQL>
```

Please note that You can also set `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'` in your session (and don't use the `TO_CHAR` in your query) as per your requirement. Also, you can use  `UTC` timezone instead of `Australia/Sydney` if you want to convert your local date to `UTC` timezone. <kbd>[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d75462fcc7aa7e1833d67bccd15c46bd)</kbd> for `UTC` conversion.

If the given data is already in `date` datatype stored in your table, then you just need to use `CAST` as follows: (`TO_DATE` is not required)

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CAST(YOUR_DATE_COLUMN
                   AS TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney', 
              'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"')
  FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```